# Add a label tag for each input tag dynamically for the DOM using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, foreach

1.The input element's id attribute and the corresponding label element should have a for attribute. The values of these two attributes must be equal. For this, needs to add a label tag for each input tag for the DOM using JQuery.

Example:

```
First Name :<input type="text" name="first_name" id="firstName" value="" maxlength="100" />
```

needs to add

```
<label for="firstName">First Name : <label> 
<input type="text" name="first_name" id="firstName" value="" maxlength="100" />
```

2.
Or this will also be fine

```
<label> First Name : <input type="text" name="first_name" id="firstName" value="" maxlength="100" /></label>
```

Thank you so much in advance :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) like

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('input').wrap(function () {
        return $('<label />', {
            for: this.id
        }).append(this.previousSibling)
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8sQqB/)

---

Or use [.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/) like

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('input').before(function () {
        return $('<label />', {
            for: this.id
        }).append(this.previousSibling)
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/N7B7P/)

Comment: Hey thank you so much. this is what I was expecting. but when I copy paste your coding to my code it gives erros :( It gets underlined. M using aptana studio to write script.I need to change the DOM.