# access the String Text before <input> in HTML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, dom

How to access the String Text before  in HTML using jQuery?

example:

```
First Name :<input type="text" name="first_name" id="firstName" value="" maxlength="100" />
```

assign this(First Name :) to a variable ?

Thank you so much inadvance :)

Comment: Not clear Please explain it

Comment: You mean first_name value to variable?

Comment: Actually what I want to do is, I need to add this "<label for="firstName"> First Name :</label> " so how to access that text infront of input tags? because I want to add label tag like that dynamicall for the DOM. Thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774573/add-a-label-tag-for-each-input-tag-dynamically-for-the-dom-using-jquery

Answer (score 4):

In this case, you can find the contents of the previous sibling of the input element

```
var label = $.trim($('#firstName').prop('previousSibling').nodeValue);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/73kNa/)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('firstName')['previousSibling'].nodeValue
```